# Terminate Roslyn script early in C#

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm loading and invoking a csx file something like this:

```
BaseScript = new ScriptBase(); // My own type
var session = engine.CreateSession(BaseScript, typeof(ScriptBase));
BaseScript.Session = session;
//...
var script = File.ReadAllText(file);
BaseScript.Session.Execute(script);
```

This script is meant to run indefinitely, and basically has a `while (true);` in there. Is there a way for me to stop it prematurely?

Also, I'm thinking about moving to Mono.Csharp, would that allow me to do this? Maybe it's a better choice overall, thoughts?

Comment: can't you run the script in a thread?

Comment: I answered my question three minutes ago, with this solution.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866383/abort-roslyn-script-execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is this: Roslyn doesn't interpret C#, it compiles it. When you call `Execute(string)`, it actually executes it right then and there. I put the call in a new thread and Abort()ed it when I needed to, which isn't especially elegant, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Aborting a thread is not a good idea, since you have no idea what the code did when you aborted it and it could leave something in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

You can control execution time of Roslyn by using Thread.

1. Create a new thread.
2. Begin execution by using`Thread.Start`.
3. Use `Thread.Join` method to control execution time. The `Thread.Join` method wait for the thread to end.

In the below code, if the thread execution time exceed more than 5 second then the thread will be become blocked.

Here is the code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
    try
    {
          // your code related to Roslyn is here
          // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

});

thread.Start();

if (!thread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
{
    thread.Interrupt();
}
```