# Abort roslyn script execution

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, roslyn

I'd like to implement timeout mechanism for scripts, executed through Roslyn, so I need a way to abort a script execution. The only solution I found so far, is executing the script inside a thread and terminating it, but it's obviously a flawed solution.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you expect the script to cooperate?

Comment: In most cases yes, but scripts will be executed on server, so I'd like a safeguard against poorly written scripts. I don't want application to hang, because somebody accidentaly wrote an infinite while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than you launching a separate process and killing that instead (to avoid the standard pitfalls of `Thread.Abort()`), that's the best you can do. Given the script code can be more or less arbitrary, there really couldn't be a better option. All it takes is your script to do `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)` and there's nothing the scripting engine could do to recover that.

Answer (score 0):

First create a new thread and put your code inside the thread as an action. Then call the `Thread.Start` method to begin execution. Use `Thread.Join` method to wait until the thread completes its execution.

In the below code, if the thread execution does not complete in 6 seconds then the thread is interrupted.

Here is the code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
    try
    {
          // your code related to Roslyn is here
          // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

});

thread.Start();

if (!thread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)))
{
    thread.Interrupt();
}
```

The above code ends compilation after 6 seconds.